# JTA 2PC - with multiple datasource

Tags: spring, jpa, jta

I am new to JTA and i am trying to implement the JTA 2 pc .In business method

I want if fun1 fails then fun3 should also  but its not happening.

```
@Transactional
fun(){

testDao1.fun1();
testDao2.fun3();
}
```

I had following things .

1. Create datasource as .I have multiple datasources

   ```
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.managed.BasicManagedDataSource"
       destroy-method="close">
       <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource" />
       <property name="url" value="${database.interimws.email.url}" />
       <property name="username" value="${database.interimws.email.username}" />
       <property name="password" value="${database.interimws.email.password}" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />        
       <property name="maxActive" value="${database.maxactive}" />
       <property name="maxIdle" value="${database.maxidle}" />
       <property name="maxWait" value="${database.maxwait}" />
   </bean>
   ```
2. having persistence unit which is of JTA type
3. created entityAMangerFactory using the above dataSource and Persistence unit 
   4.getting the javax.transaction.TransactionManager and Usertransaction object from Server and configured spring jta for annotation
4. Having a bussiness class which is annotated as transactional.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have XA-type drivers for every database that participates in two-phase commit; otherwise, it won't work.

How are you testing this?  Do you have a mock version of DAO1 that throws an exception?

Comment: Thanks for response .I am using oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource and org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource .Both are XA type

Comment: And i am not  getting expected result when testDao1.fun1() falis testDao2.fun3() does not rollback ..setting BasicManagedDataSource defaultAutoCommit=false.

Comment: JTA Does not commit if i set the defaultAutoCommit=false